# Que signifie « ta go » ou « tago » ?

Tags: sens, registre-familier, langage-des-jeunes

Récemment, j'ai entendu un jeune s'adresser à quelqu'un en lui disant *hé ta go* ou *hé tago* (je ne sais pas comment cela s'écrit). Je pense que ce mot est issu du langage des jeunes.

Pour le contexte, c'était dans une rue et c'était énoncé comme une phrase à part entière sur un ton d'interpellation ou de description.

Pourriez-vous m'éclairer sur la signification de ce terme ?

Comment: Pourrais-tu préciser le contexte ?

Comment: C'était dans la rue et le jeune s'adressait à un couple mais je ne sais pas si cela aide.

Comment: Dans la rue de quelle ville, déjà ? Est-tu sûr que c'était exactement prononcé [tago] et pas quelque chose qui ressemble ? C'était une phrase à soi tout seul ? Dit sur quel ton ?

Comment: J'ai édité ma question pour préciser tout ça.

Comment: Tiens, drôle. J'ai appris aujourd'hui en lisant wikipedia que go était utilisé dans le nouveau dialecte pour dire fille, meuf ou un truc dans le genre. Ça pourait être ça ? J'essayerai de retrouver le lien.

Comment: Québec, France...? Je connais une expression au Québec, mais elle est rarement utilisée et seulement chez les plus âgés.

Comment: @Zonata: la question concerne la France mais il peut être intéressant d'avoir une idée sur ce que cette expression signifie au Québec.

Comment: @Zistoloen Une go est un coup de poing pour nous, comme le montre cette caricature: https://tbearlibre.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/on-se-donne-le-go.jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Hé ta go !

signifie exactement :

> Hé ta gonzesse !

([Source](http://fr.pourelles.yahoo.com/10-expressions-jeunes-expliqu%C3%A9es-aux-parents-085749675.html))

Answer (score 16):

Je confirme (mais je ne peux pas encore commenter) avec un lien qui fournit un exemple d'utilisation dans une chanson de 1998.

> **go** *nom féminin* : Femme, fille, petite amie.

[Go - Le Dictionnaire de la Zone](http://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/index.php?page=definition&mots=go&terme=go)

Comment: Probablement une abréviation poussé à l'extrême de "gonzesse" soit dit en passant.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse très proche de la réalité.

Comment: Je confirme également, l'expression est très utilisée en banlieue et à Paris chez les jeunes :)

Answer (score 8):

Une idée éventuellement...

> C'est ta *go* ? (= ta meuf / = ta copine)

avec les variantes (entre autres)

- Hé ! (sous-entendu : c'est) ta go ?!
- Héééé... (admiration) ta go !
- Et ta go ? (sous-entendu... elle est là ? elle vient ? ou autre)

---

(édition : oui Stéphane je lis ton commentaire après coup, mais c'est couramment utilisé dans le sens de *fille / jeune fille*. Je l'ai entendu (principalement dans la bouche de locuteurs situés dans la tranche d'age 20-30 ans) en région lyonnaise et un peu à Paris il me semble. Plus rare dans l'est, je vis à Nancy et je l'entends peu.)

Comment: J'ai vérifié et *tago* est bien un prénom mais je n'ai pas l'impression que les personnes se connaissaient. L'idée de la copine est par contre probable.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse très proche de la réalité.

Comment: Nan, assurément, dans ce context, ce n'est ni un prénom, ni une exclamation "hééé", ni un "hé" pour "c'est" (jamais entendu ça) mais bien `Et ta go ?!`

Comment: @TCHdvlp Oui, ça semblerait crédible.... en l'absence de la jeune fille désignée. Mais on ignore si elle se trouvait à côté de lui à ce moment-là, donc il me semble que tu vas un peu vite aux conclusions...

Comment: Je confirme que je n'ai jamais entendu ça dans l'Est (Nancy pendant vingt ans, maintenant Metz et Luxembourg), mais nous avons nos bonnes expressions bien lorraines pour compenser.

Answer (score 8):

J'ai découvert récemment que c'est un mot utilisé à la base en Nouchi, un argot ivoirien rependu en Afrique de l'ouest comparable au verlan dans les banlieue d'où tire son origine ce mot qui veut dire meuf, fille ou femme.

Answer (score 4):

Plus exactement, on écrit ça : "Gow"
 Ca veut dire meuf chez les jeunes. 
T'es ma gow = t'es ma meuf

Comment: jamais vu écrit ça *gow* pour ma part

Answer (score 3):

Je confirme qu'une "go" est une fille, et souvent une petite amie, d'où le ta de "ta go".

Il me semble que ça vient de l'ivoirien.
L'expression viens de Paris et existe depuis plus de 10 ans, notamment dans des textes de rap, mais commence à se généraliser dans le reste de la France.

Answer (score 2):

Ça s'écrit ta go ou ma go,...
C'est un nom pour dire ma copine comme on dirait pour un ami de mauvaise fréquentation: mon sheguey

Answer (score 0):

Une go vient du ["nouchi"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouchi), l'argot ivoirien qui signifie fille, meuf.

Comme le mot "enjailler" qu'utilise La Fouine dans un de ses tubes qui veut dire être joyeux, heureux, content, enthousiasmé.

Comment: Plusieurs réponses commencent à se répéter..

Answer (score 0):

"Ta Go" signifie ta petite amie ou petite copine car le mot Go fait référence au mot gonzesse

Comment: Il est inutile de faire une nouvelle réponse si on n'a aucun élément nouveau à apporter aux réponses déjà existantes.